# loose coupling of notifications in SOA

Tags: soa

The solution is composed of an orchestration process services and multiple legacy applications in charge of making CRUD operations on the domain entities. 
Every time an update, add or delete statement is executed by these legacy applications a notification is sent by the entity owner application. 
In the modeling phase we decided to map the entities fine-grained. In this way every CRUD operation can rise thousands of notifications(up to 20k) resulting to blocking users activity for a while becouse entity persistence and notification sending are combined in the same transaction. This can be inacceptable when it takes more than 120 seconds.

What i wanted to do is separate the user activity in legacy applications from entity persistence and notification sending deferring these to a specific application service(for example). I know the best would be deferring these activities to a background thread in the user application but as i mentioned i'm using very old legacy applications. Is there any SOA design patterns that can be applied to this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is "[Decoupled invocation](http://arnon.me/soa-patterns/decoupled-invocation/)". You accept the request and put it in a (persistent) queue and send an acknowledgment to the user that the request has been received. Depending on the scenarioYou can send an additional reply (e.g. by email) when the message has been fully processed.

[image].

Comment: Hi Arnon, Thank you for the reply. I have two additional questions: What do you mean by Edge service? is this a kind of Process, Business or Application Service?